# ie11 bootstrap select extrange behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-select

I have a problem with [this web](http://www.cbnvillas.com/nueva/) that is driving me crazy.

On Windows IE11 first load, search form doesn't charge correctly (no problem with any other navigators, even IEdge).

For some strange reason (quite sure not so strange) if I push F5 (update) rapidly several times (5 is a good number) then the page charges correctly.

Can anyone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In head side, this display mode pages in browsers IE

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

change on

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to include the latest available standard display mode